# Nginx 301 redirect if string is given

Tags: nginx, redirect

I would like to create a permanent redirect for specific querys inside my nginx server block. As example on my current url links to the php script have been:

```
website.com/?hash=12345
```

So i need to change this to `website.com/folder/?hash=12345`
Is there a way to redirect permanent only if the parameter ?hash= is given inside the query and leave all other querys how they are?

Edit: I did some testings with this here

```
        location ~* /.*hash\=.*/ {
     rewrite ^ https://mysite.eu/bluetracker/$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

but Sadly this is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Just check for the existence of the argument.

```
location / {
    if ($arg_hash) {
        return 301 /folder/$is_args$args;
    }

    # everything else...
}
```

Note here, that `$is_args` returns a `?` if there is a query string, and an empty string otherwise. And `$args` returns the entire query string.